# How do I fix my Problem with ComboBoxes in Java Swing?

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, combobox

As the title says I can't fill my Comboboxes.

Ok, so I'm making a program for a football club for managing events and players.
The idea is that I have a SQLite Database and a Java Swing Program with 2 ComboBoxes, one for the Type (Players or Events) and the other for the (The Player or Event Names). When the Type Combobox Selected Item changes it should reload all the items from the second ComboBox i.e. make a Database connection and get either all Player or all Event names.

Here is my code

```
javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel window;
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox2;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JComboBox<String> type = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Spieler", "Events"});

    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton changeButton;

    String selected = (String) type.getSelectedItem();

    Util util = new Util();

    MainWindow() throws SQLException{
        setConfigurations();
        reloadSelection(selected);
        type.addActionListener(e -> {
            try {reloadSelection((selected));}
            catch (SQLException ex) {throw new RuntimeException(ex);}

        });
        addButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("not yet implemented"));
        deleteButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("not yet implemented"));
        changeButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("not yet implemented"));
    }

    private void  reloadSelection(String selected) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = util.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        String[] arr = new String[0];
        String query;
        System.out.println(selected);
        if(selected.equals("Spieler")) {
            query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Players;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("firstName") + rs.getString("lastName");
                arr = name.split("\n");
            }
        }
        /*else if(selected.equals("Events")) {
            query = "SELECT eventName FROM Events;";
        } */
        comboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(arr));
        util.closeConnection(c);
    }
    private void setConfigurations() {
        setContentPane(window);
        setName("LineUp");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(350, 175);
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 175));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 175));
    }

}
```

This theoretically works but returns me this:
[image]

It also says that I overewrite code with

`private JComboBox<String> type = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Spieler", "Events"});`

But when I put the decleration in the Configuration Function it outputs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "selected" is null

Which is understandable because in the beginning it's null and so i can't make comparisons.

Can you help me fix this?

I wanted it to reload the second Combobox when I changed the selected Item of the first combobox

Comment: I would, start by loading the results into a `List` of some kind.  `List` has a `toArray` method which can be used to generate the array you seem to be passing to the combobox model

Comment: Change `if(selected.equals("Spieler")) {` to `if("Spieler".equals(selected)) {` this will get you over your `NullPointerException`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `arr = name.split("\n");` is never going to result in the expected array, use a `List` instead

Comment: "*it's null and so i can't make comparisons.*" --> `if (selected != null && selected.equals("Spieler"))`, or maybe better `if (seleceted == null) { /* clear combo box */ else if (selected.equals("Spieler")) { /* fill combo box */ }`; or, with newer Java versions, even better IMHO `switch (selected) { case null ... case "Spieler" ...`  (I would also have constants/enum for `"Spieler"` and `"Events"`)

Comment: BTW you don't even need an array or list - `JComboBox` has methods to add and remove items

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that...

```
String name = rs.getString("firstName") + rs.getString("lastName");
arr = name.split("\n");
```

is never going to do what you want it to do.  Apart from the fact that it's very unlikely that `name` will contain `\n`, you're assigning a new value to `arr` on each iteration, so at best, you'd get the last row.

Instead, I'd recommend using a `List` of some kind instead.  `List` has a `toArray` method which you can use to feed the results to the `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

I would also recommend taking a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (as a consideration of best practices).

Something like...

```
private void reloadSelection(String selected) throws SQLException {
    if ("Spieler".equals(selected)) {
        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>(32);
        try (Connection c = util.getConnection(); 
                PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Players"); 
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("firstName") + " " + rs.getString("lastName");
                rows.add(name.trim());
            }
        }
        comboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()])));
    }
}
```

would likely produce more desirable results.

Also beware, creating a `Connection` is typically an expensive operation, instead, if you can, create it once at the start of the app and close it when the app closes.